# aptana studio delete line

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

I'm testing out Aptana Studio to do some javascript development I want to know if there is a shortcut to delete a whole line. Or if there is a way to create some kind of macro to do it.

I am running windows, and I know that I can click `Ctrl+Shift+Del` but that doesn't actually do what I want it to do. In VS when you click `Shift+Del` it doesn't matter where the cursor is on the line it will delete the whole line. 
To do the same in Aptana I need to:

1. Click `Home` to get me to the beginning of the line
2. Click `Ctrl+Shift+Del` to delete the content of the line
3. Click `Ctrl+Shift+Del` to delete the line

This may seem small, but I do this action all the time in VS and I've grown accustomed to it.

Anyone have any ideas to help me out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just figured it out:

It's quite simple: `Ctrl+D`

Also if you want to change the key binding you can

1. Go to menu Window -> Preferences
2. Go to General -> Keys
3. Find Command 'Delete Line' and then bind it to your desired key combo(like `Shift+Delete`)